# creating horizontal menu with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sidebar

I want to create a menu like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7638/) but without using ng-repeat:

```
<ul class="sidebar-navi">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showChilds(item)">
        <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-menu"><i class="fa fa-angle-left sidebar-nav-indicator sidebar-nav-mini-hide"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs sidebar-nav-icon"></i>{{item.name}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li ng-show="item.active">
                <span>First</span>
            </li>
            <li ng-show="item.active">
                <span>Second</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the problem is that I didn't find a way to pass parameter to this function showChilds (the current li) I tried to work with id but it didn't work:

```
                    <ul class="sidebar-navi">
                        <li id="first" ng-click="showChilds(first)">
                            <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-menu"><i class="fa fa-angle-left sidebar-nav-indicator sidebar-nav-mini-hide"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs sidebar-nav-icon"></i>1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-show="first.active">
                                    <span>First</span>
                                </li>
                                <li ng-show="first.active">
                                    <span>Second</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="second" ng-click="showChilds(second)">
                            <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-menu"><i class="fa fa-angle-left sidebar-nav-indicator sidebar-nav-mini-hide"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs sidebar-nav-icon"></i>2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-show="second.active">
                                    <span>First</span>
                                </li>
                                <li ng-show="second.active">
                                    <span>Second</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

and my controller will contain only this function

```
  $scope.showChilds = function (item) {
    item.active = !item.active
  }
```

I don't want to use $scope.items anymore

Comment: where is your code without ng-repeat?

Comment: where do you set the value of item? It's a user input?

Comment: please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your HTML. If you are not using ng-repeat then you can use ng-init to initialize one variable and toggle that variable on ng-click to show/hide sub menus. Your updated sample is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9bpbv53j/4/)

```
 <ul class="sidebar-navi">
                    <li id="first" ng-click="first = !first" ng-init="first = false">
                        <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-menu"><i class="fa fa-angle-left sidebar-nav-indicator sidebar-nav-mini-hide"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs sidebar-nav-icon"></i>1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-show="first">
                                <span>First</span>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-show="first">
                                <span>Second</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="second" ng-click="second = !second" ng-init="second = false">
                        <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-menu"><i class="fa fa-angle-left sidebar-nav-indicator sidebar-nav-mini-hide"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs sidebar-nav-icon"></i>2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-show="second">
                                <span>First</span>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-show="second">
                                <span>Second</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: I don't want to use items list anymore I want to use only html please check the update